# Count filenumber in directory with blank in its name

Tags: shell, unix

```
     If you want a breakdown of how many files are in each dir under your current dir:

 for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; do 
    echo -n $i": " ; 
   (find $i -type f | wc -l) ; 
 done
```

It does not work when the directory name has a blank in the name. Can anyone here tell me how I must edite this shell script so that such directory names also accepted for counting its file contents?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code suffers from a common issue described in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29.

In your case you could do this instead:

```
for i in */; do 
    echo -n "${i%/}: " 
    find "$i" -type f | wc -l 
done
```

Comment: thanks, but can you tell me, if my solution (1) do something wrong in particular directory/filenames? I do get with this the requested results. Still learning bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with all types of file names:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'printf "%s: %i\n" "$1" "$(find "$1" -type f | wc -l)"' Counter {} \;
```

#### How it works

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`

  This finds the directories just as you were doing
- `-exec sh -c 'printf "%s: %i\n" "$1" "$(find "$1" -type f | wc -l)"' Counter {} \;`

  This feeds each directory name to a shell script which counts the files, similarly to what you were doing.

  There are some tricks here:  `Counter {}` are passed as arguments to the shell script.  `Counter` becomes `$0` (which is only used if the shell script generates an error.  `find` replaces `{}` with the name of a directory it found and this will be available to the shell script as `$1`.  This is done is a way that is safe for all types of file names.

  Note that, wherever `$1` is used in the script, it is inside double-quotes.  This protects it for word splitting or other unwanted shell expansions.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution what I have to consider:
[Consider_this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html)

```
  #!/bin/bash
  SAVEIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
  for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
    echo -n " $i: ";
    (find $i -type f | wc -l) ;
  done
  IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: That still fails on names that contain newlines. And why did you add `\b` to `IFS`?